# Meteor - Images don't load on mobile (cordova)

Tags: cordova, meteor, angular-meteor

Images from both, gravatar url and local CollectionFS, aren't loaded on mobile (cordova) but works great on the web client.

mobile-config.js already has http and https * access rules.

```
*Meteor version 1.2.1
*Packages:
angular:angular-material
angularui:angular-ui-router
planettraining:material-design-icons
standard-minifiers
meteor-base
mobile-experience
mongo
session
jquery
tracker
logging
reload
random
ejson
spacebars
check
angular
accounts-password
accounts-ui
urigo:angular-blaze-template
jparker:gravatar
accounts-facebook
accounts-google
raix:push
matb33:collection-hooks
dburles:collection-helpers
email
tap:i18n
msavin:mongol
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:gridfs
mdg:camera
dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
meteorhacks:kadira
launch-screen
daniel:auto-nprogress
momentjs:moment
crosswalk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with permissions on the mobile-config file. As the app uses collectionFS and GridFS it needs to had set App.accessRule("blob:*") so it can access our blob images on Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova looks for localhost:3000/ImageName.jpg instead of YourMeteorIP:3000/ImageName.jpg